# Display image to 2 Collection View in 1 View Controller

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, alamofire

i want to display 2 images i get from different url and different API using alamofire in 2 collection view. i have 2 collection view in single view controller. first API need parameters while second API doesn't need paramters so i declare parameters once.

here's my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

var url = [String]()
var secondUrl = [String]()

let parameters = [

   "data": 1  
]

let collectionViewAIdentifier = "CollectionViewACell"
let collectionViewBIdentifier = "CollectionViewBCell"

@IBOutlet weak var mainCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondMainCollectionView: UICollectionView!

let collectionViewA = UICollectionView()
let collectionViewB = UICollectionView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionViewA.delegate = self
    collectionViewB.delegate = self

    collectionViewA.dataSource = self
    collectionViewB.dataSource = self

    self.view.addSubview(collectionViewA)
    self.view.addSubview(collectionViewB)

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "URL", parameters:  parameters).responseJSON { response in

        if let value = response.result.value {

            let json = JSON(value)

            let data = json["data"].arrayValue

            let status = json["api_status"].intValue

            if status == 1 {

                print(json["api_message"].stringValue)

                for datas in data {
        self.url.append(datas["companies_photo"].stringValue)
                }
            } else {
                print(json["api_message"].stringValue)
            }
                self.mainCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "URL").responseJSON { response in

        if let value = response.result.value {

            let json = JSON(value)

            let data = json["data"].arrayValue

            let status = json["api_status"].intValue

            if status == 1 {

                print(json["api_message"].stringValue)

                for datas in data {

                    self.secondUrl.append(datas["image"].stringValue)
                }
            } else {
                print(json["api_message"].stringValue)
            }
            self.secondMainCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.collectionViewA {
        return url.count
    }

    return secondUrl.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == self.collectionViewA {
    let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(collectionViewAIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

    let imageUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: url[indexPath.row])

    if let url = imageUrl {
        cellA.mainImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url)
    }
    return cellA
}else {
        let cellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(collectionViewBIdentifier, forIndexPath:  indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell

        let imageUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: secondUrl[indexPath.row])

        if let url = imageUrl {
            cellB.secondMainImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url)
        }

        return cellB
    }
}
```

i have each image outlet on different CollectionViewCell.swift

the build succeded, but it print SIGABRT error with debug

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

Comment: Can u check if layout in xib fir collectionview is set to flow.. U haven't implemented uicollectionviewflowlayoutdelegate methods

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented uicollectionviewflowlayoutdelegate methods... SizeforItemAtINDEX

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to register class

```
 collectionViewA.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: collectionViewAIdentifier)



collectionViewB.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: collectionViewBIdentifier)
```